# Use object in Route with PlayFramework : Reverse routing

Tags: binding, routes, playframework, symfony-1.4

**Is it possible to generate an url mapped by an object ?**
The [Pojo Object Mapping](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/controllers#POJOobjectbinding) is a native function of PlayFramework (1.2.2), but what about the **reverse routing**?

I would like to do this :

Java:

```
class MyControler extends Controller {
    public static function myAction(MyObject o) {}
}
```

Route: (something like this ? If it's possible, i don't know the syntax to do it !)

```
GET    /folder/{myObject.name}/{myObject.id}      MyController.myAction(myObject)
```

Template :

```
<a href="@{MyControler.myAction(myObject)}">Go</a>
```

**Expected result** :

```
<a href="/folder/xxNamexx/33">Go</a>
```

*(I have a Symfony background, and I search an equivalent to the [Object Route Class](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05#chapter_05_object_route_class))*

I think Play! don't support this functionnaly, could someone confirm or refute this idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you simply try it out?

Comment: This code doesn't work. But maybe my syntax is incorrect, or there is an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Julien Richard-Foy, there is no solution.

So I propose a workaround, a little ugly because the route will be describe twice.
This quick solution breaks the MVC model, but it's possible to do otherwise, sending a UrlHelper to the template for exemple.

In your model, add a `generateUrlDetail()` method :

```
public String generateUrlDetail() {
    return String.format("/myRoute/%s/%d-%s.html", JavaExtensions.slugify(this.foo.name), this.id, JavaExtensions.slugify(this.bar));
}
```

**Tips** : Play! allows to define a route with more identifiers than necessary. So it's possible to write a route with 2+ variables, but only the ID will be used in the action.

```
GET /myRoute/{foo}/{<[0-9]+>id}-{bar}.html           Foo.detail(id)
```

And in your template :

```
<a href="${myObject.generateUrlDetail()}">Go</a>
Render : <a href="/myRoute/foo-name/13-bar-description.html">Go</a>
```

And it works :)

Answer (score 3):

What you’re asking for is not currently possible.

So the usual workaround is this pattern:

```
GET     /folder/{id}            MyController.myAction

class MyController extends Controller {
    public static void myAction(Long id) {
        MyObject o = MyObject.findById(id);
        // You may probably want to add the following line:
        notFoundIfNull(o);
        // … then your code here
    }
}
```

The solution is not so verbose, but I agree that further version of Play! should allow a more simple syntax, similar to what you suggested.

Comment: This method works very well (i do this), but i need url more seo-friendly. See my workaround above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, **if** it is going to work, it will need the package declaration :

```
GET    /folder/{models.myObject.name}/{models.myObject.id}
```

Comment: Not possible, the "." create an exception (Play! try to read a regex)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. Bind with the id of the object. Works for me 
`<a href="@{MyControler.myAction().add('o.id', myObject.id)}">Go</a>`

Comment: What is your result with this syntax ? I have a route like "/myControler/myAction?o.id=X", it's not my expected result at all.